# how to delete refreshtoken and access token when user logout oauth 2.0?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

i tried with ....

```
 <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logoutsuccess" logouturl="/logout/>
```

but it is not working properly....
i want to clear everything like refresh token and access token session , cookies when user logout....

my security-servlet.xml looks like this

```
<!-- Protected resources -->
<sec:http create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/data/user/*"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spring-boot application I will:
1. get OAuth2AccessToken
2. using it will delete OAuth2RefreshToken
3. and then delete itself

```
@Component
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler 
        extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
        implements LogoutSuccessHandler {


    private static final String BEARER_AUTHENTICATION = "Bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);

        if (token != null && token.startsWith(BEARER_AUTHENTICATION)) {
            String accessTokenValue = token.split(" ")[1];

            OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(accessTokenValue);
            if (oAuth2AccessToken != null) {
                OAuth2RefreshToken oAuth2RefreshToken = oAuth2AccessToken.getRefreshToken();
                if (oAuth2RefreshToken != null)
                    tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(oAuth2RefreshToken);

                tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
            }
        }

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do these things into sessionDestroyedListener...almost look like this..
In this code i am updating lastLogout date ..you can do what you want

```html
@Component("sessionDestroyedEventListener")
public class SessionDestroyedEventListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent>{


// private static Logger logger = BaseLogger.getLogger(AuthenticationEventListener.class);
 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
 
 public void setAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
  this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
 }
 /**
  * Capture sessionDestroyed event and update lastLogout date after session destroyed of particular user.
  */
 @Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent appEvent) {
  SessionDestroyedEvent event = (SessionDestroyedEvent) appEvent;
  Object obj = null;
  UserInfo userInfo = null;
  ArrayList<SecurityContext> sc = (ArrayList<SecurityContext>) event.getSecurityContexts();
  Iterator<SecurityContext> itr = sc.iterator();

  while (itr.hasNext()) {
   obj = itr.next().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

   if (obj instanceof UserInfo) {
    userInfo = (UserInfo) obj;
   } else {
    String userCode = (String) obj;
    if (userCode == null || "".equals(userCode)) {
     userCode = "UnDefinedUser";
    }
    userInfo = new UserInfo(userCode);

   }

     //authenticationService.updateLastLogoutDate(userInfo.getUsername());
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to solve this using configuration ?

Comment: <logout logout-url="/logout"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>.....I have using this configuration.,..but according to me for making it sure you can don this.